# How do i make my google web app searchable on google?

Tags: google-app-engine, search-engine

I have started to develop a web app on google's app engine and i wish to make the static content on the site searchable on google.

For example, my app is at http://xxxxxxx.appspot.com/ and on it there is only some random text like 'form bell road smear sky orange fan glass key'.

When i google  for 'form bell road smear' for example or the title of the site for that matter , i get no results - cant find the site.

Does anyone know how to make a appengine site google-able?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google has to discover your site -- it can't just "search the web" without some sort of index. Basically, to submit your URL to Google, you can either:

- add your URL directly: http://www.google.com/addurl/
- use Webmaster Tools: http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Don't expect Google to crawl your site the moment you submit it, though. Also, it might not even be indexed; see the Webmaster Help for more info: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=34444.

EDIT: thanks for the upvote, I can now place more links ;)

Comment: +1 for `addurl` and `Webmaster Tools`. Now you have more than 10 to put the link :)